# cookie is not stored on chrome application

Tags: javascript, html

The cookie url_user is not stored, why?

This is the index.html:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="objectosPredef.js" pe="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" rel="noopener" target="_blank" href="mystyles.css">
</head>

<body>  

<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="SetCoockie()">ESTABLECE COOCKIE</button>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the javascript "objectosPredef.js":

```
function SetCoockie() {

    document.cookie = "url_usuario = myname";
}
```

[image]

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is OK, but it needs to be run from a server you will see your hostname is like `http://localhost` or `http://example.com` but you are running from the file system `file://`

You can use the LiveServer extension for vs code to run a local server for your HTML file.

Answer (score 4):

Browsers doesnt support to store cookies for url `file://` .